# How to create .NET core lib targeting WPF on Windows?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

I have the following projects in my solution (simplified):

- Helpers, a .NET Core 5.0 Library with general helper methods
- ConsoleApp, a .NET Core 5.0 Console Application, which is using the Helpers.lib. The ConsoleApp has to run on Windows AND Linux.
- HelpersWpfCore, the problem, this shall be a .NET Core 5.0 Library, which uses the Helpers.lib and contains some WPF functionally like support for printing, documents, UserControls etc.
- WpfApp, a .NET Core 5.0 WPF Application, this has to use the Helpers.lib AND the HelpersWpfCore.lib. WpfApp only has to run on Windows.

My problem is that I can't compile the HelpersWpf lib. I'm getting errors like

```
  Error CS0246: Der Typ- oder Namespacename "IValueConverter" wurde nicht gefunden (möglicherweise fehlt eine using-Direktive oder ein Assemblyverweis). (15, 31)

  Error CS0246: Der Typ- oder Namespacename "BindingMode" wurde nicht gefunden (möglicherweise fehlt eine using-Direktive oder ein Assemblyverweis). (15, 13)

  Error CS0246: Der Typ- oder Namespacename "DependencyProperty" wurde nicht gefunden (möglicherweise fehlt eine using-Direktive oder ein Assemblyverweis). (14, 95)

  Error CS0246: Der Typ- oder Namespacename "FrameworkElement" wurde nicht gefunden (möglicherweise fehlt eine using-Direktive oder ein Assemblyverweis). (14, 38)

  Error CS0234: Der Typ- oder Namespacename "Shapes" ist im Namespace "System.Windows" nicht vorhanden. (Möglicherweise fehlt ein Assemblyverweis.) (7, 22)

  Error CS0234: Der Typ- oder Namespacename "Data" ist im Namespace "System.Windows" nicht vorhanden. (Möglicherweise fehlt ein Assemblyverweis.) (6, 22)

  Error CS0234: Der Typ- oder Namespacename "Controls" ist im Namespace "System.Windows" nicht vorhanden. (Möglicherweise fehlt ein Assemblyverweis.) (5, 22)

  Error CS0246: Der Typ- oder Namespacename "Adorner" wurde nicht gefunden (möglicherweise fehlt eine using-Direktive oder ein Assemblyverweis). (8, 23)

  Error CS0246: Der Typ- oder Namespacename "UIElement" wurde nicht gefunden (möglicherweise fehlt eine using-Direktive oder ein Assemblyverweis). (8, 54)

  Error CS0234: Der Typ- oder Namespacename "Documents" ist im Namespace "System.Windows" nicht vorhanden. (Möglicherweise fehlt ein Assemblyverweis.) (2, 22)

  Error CS0246: Der Typ- oder Namespacename "DrawingContext" wurde nicht gefunden (möglicherweise fehlt eine using-Direktive oder ein Assemblyverweis). (10, 42)

  Error CS0234: Der Typ- oder Namespacename "Media" ist im Namespace "System.Windows" nicht vorhanden. (Möglicherweise fehlt ein Assemblyverweis.) (3, 22)

  Error CS0234: Der Typ- oder Namespacename "Documents" ist im Namespace "System.Windows" nicht vorhanden. (Möglicherweise fehlt ein Assemblyverweis.) (2, 22)
```

("wurde nicht gefunden" => "was not found")

In HelpersWpfCore -> Dependencies -> Frameworks only "Microsoft.NETCore.App" is listed.

How can I achieve that the missing classes will be included in the lib?

I'm aware that this is .NET Core and not .NET Framework anymore (this has been earlier and with 4.7.2 it worked fine). But since WPF core apps only run on Windows I think that this should be possible, especially in 2021 and with Core 5.0, isn't it?

Due to circumstances, switching back to .NET Framework for the WpfApp using Multitargeting isn't a solution for me.

Comment: Oh, I forgot: I'm using VisualStudio 2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have created the project from the wrong template.

In the solution expolorer double click on the project. This will open the project file. Alternatively open the .csproj file directly.

Make sure you are using the correct target framework moniker by checking the `<TargetFramework>` tag.

.NET 5 is cross platform. It only supports cross platform libraries. `Adorner`, `UIElement` etc. are Windows (or WPF) targeting specialized classes contained in Windows specific libraries. (UI related libraries or frameworks like WPF are never cross platform compatible).

Since you are using Windows specific resources, you have to specify the OS explicitly when configuring the project's target framework.
This will remove the library's cross platform compatibility of course.
You can find a list of target framework monikers in the [Microsoft Docs: .NET 5+ OS-specific TFMs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#net-5-os-specific-tfms)

Therefore, the correct target framework moniker would be `net5.0-windows` (this will add the missing reference to `Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App` to your project's dependencies):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>

  ...

</Project>
```

Note that to finally enable the proper SDK (WPF in your case), you have to add the corresponding MSBuild property (see example above):

`<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>`

See [Microsoft Docs: MSBuild reference for .NET Desktop SDK projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props-desktop)

Comment: I tried changing the TargetFramework from "net5.0" to "net5.0-windows" before, but doing this AND adding "<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>" finally did the trick. This reduced most of my errors. Thanks a lot!

Comment: > It looks like you have created the project from the wrong template.
I suspected this before, but I didn't find a proper one. Maybe one have to install an additional template before?
And which one?

Comment: Anyway, now there are still some namespace which aren't resolved yet:
a) System.Drawing (for using e.g. the bitmap class) and
b) System.Windows.Forms (for using the standard dialogs from WinForms, which WPF has still missing after so many years).
I could live without a), because I don't need my Image classes for this solution and comment them out, but do you have a workaround for b)?

Comment: @HansHeinz You should not use System.Drawing. It contains WinForms classes only. They depend on the old GDI+ rendering engine while WPF uses the modern DirectX engine. Take a look at the [System.Windows.Media namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media?view=net-5.0), which contains the equvivalent classes targeting DirectX. Otherwise you would have to install System.Drawing using the NuGet package manager, since the namespace is not WPF. Same applies to System.Windows.Forms.

Comment: To use common dialogs take a look at the [Microsoft.Win32 namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32?view=net-5.0). It contains a OpenFileDialog and SaveFileDialog, which are the preferable dialogs.

Comment: Also prefer the use of the WPF [BitmapImage Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage?view=net-5.0#examples) (instead of System.Drawing). Avoid System.Drawing.